# Is gRPC a good choice for my scenario?

Tags: design, design-patterns

Im starting to develop a visually-simple but infrastructural-ly robust real time multiplayer game to show off my backend skills and hopefully get a job at Blizzard or something like that.

The game is simple: a multiplayer snake game.

I'm aiming to have a game session supporting up to 8 players, all connecting to a single dedicated server.

Because of the high "latency-sensitiveness" of the game I was wondering if a duplex gRPC is a good choice for communication channel, or if perhaps there's a better/more-recommended way to handle this?

Is that so or there is a better approach?

Comment: Why gRPC and not plain ol websockets? What features of gRPC do you need that websockets don't have? If you can answer that, you have your answer.

Comment: I believe that the binary approach of gRPC will save a lot of bandwidth... on comparisons over the web, the performance of gRPC seems to beat web sockets... and also, my client will not be a browser (not that this is a blocker, I just like to point it out)

Comment: In which case what is your argument for using gRPC over TCP/UDP/uTP? Also just a point, gRPC is built on top of HTTP/2 (which is WebSockets). It isn't going to be any faster/lower bandwidth than them.

Comment: @Leonardo If you do not use a web browser, why gRPC at all? Why not use a heavily compressed binary format over TCP or UDP, directly? There are very efficient serialization libraries for almost every mainstream language that will likely beat performance of gRPC, plus affording better control over how you handle connection issues. These are all question you do need to ask yourself, how you answer these will tell you if gRPC is a good fit.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give any good answer, but I'll share something with you. Long story short, there's a small but dedicated team of developers maintaining a game named RoR. RoR was an EA game which reached EOL a long time ago. The team keeps working on it and part of the source code is published in Github. Back then, when I checked out the project, it was an RPC-like client-server system. Their current source code is not published for obvious reasons but they are open and looking for volunteers to maintain the game. Maybe they can give you the insights you need.

Comment: @Polygnome "Why not use a heavily compressed binary format over TCP or UDP, directly?" because im not aware of any... would you mind name a few so I can compare?

Comment: @Laiv thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Polygnome `If you do not use a web browser, why gRPC at all?`, well, I tested 2 days ago... I went from "I know gRPC exists" to https://github.com/Leonardo-Ferreira/gRPC-Chat in under 6 hours! I liked the tooling and found it very easy to get going also!

Comment: @Leonardo You literally only have to google "fast serialization library in <your language>" and usually also get some good benchmarks.

Comment: @Polygnome `If you do not use a web browser, why gRPC at all` - you seem to imply that gRPC somehow a common thing in browser, when in reality [it is not](https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/#:~:text=the%20new%20protocol.-,The%20gRPC%2DWeb%20Spec,frames%20are%20inaccessible%20in%20browsers.). There is gRPC-web wrapper but it is not as polished as non-browser packages and have limitations.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar that was clearly, and obviously, in the context of "will save a lot of bandwidth." And it certainly makes sense. If one's not bound by HTTP/2, as in this case since it will not be a browser based game, one can freely go beyond gRPC.

Comment: Came here just looking for performance benchmarks, but I can tell you, despite what anyone says, the short answer is yes! I know I'm late to the party here, but just wanted to throw my two cents in. Since you seem to be concerned about response times, id stick with UTC. However, if you wanted to just do it for the fun of it, there's no reason you can't. I will be making a small game using gRPC; but then again, it's only as a hobby, and I don't expect the game to scale, so I don't have much worry for bandwidth.